# mssql date field performance issues

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

I am trying to imporve performance on the below query which runs for around 3 seconds. I am new to execution plan analysis and indexing in SQL.

I already have indexing on DateFrom and DateTo fileds (2 separate index and one combined index). I tried creating indexing on DateLiveActual filed, but none of these indexes are showing up in the execution plan.

Could you please help me optimizing the query?

```
declare @today date = convert(date,GETUTCDATE());
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

SELECT 
            S.LocationId
            ,SBP.CurrencyId
            ,SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN S.ServiceStatusId = 1 THEN COALESCE (SBP.MRR, 0)
                    ELSE 0
                END) AS ActiveMRR   
            ,MIN(S.DateLiveActual) AS MinServiceDateLiveActual
        FROM dbo.service_Service AS S 
        INNER JOIN dbo.billing_ServiceBillingPeriod AS SBP ON SBP.ServiceId = S.Id 
        WHERE 
            SBP.DateFrom <= @today AND (SBP.DateTo >= @today OR SBP.DateTo IS NULL)
        GROUP BY S.LocationId, SBP.CurrencyId
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no much you can do. As you can conclude from arrow thickness in your execution plan, your where clause is not very selective. You can try to reduce number of bytes read from billing_ServiceBillingPeriod using smaller index tree:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_DateRange
ON billing_ServiceBillingPeriod(DateFrom, DateTo)
INCLUDE (CurrencyId,ServiceID,MRR)
```

There is not much you can do with HASH join if there are many rows (thick arrow). Merge join is faster, but needs ordered resultsets (if dates are used records are ordered on dates, service_Service.Id is unordered). Again, you can only reduce disk usage creating hash tables from smaller set.

Comment: The indexing improved the perf by 1 sec, Thanks for the input.. However the Min(DateLiveScheduled) takes 1 sec. Is there anyway we could speed that up. Actually its on the service_Service table, so SQL takes PK's Index by default.